# How to interpolate medical images of different ranges

Tags: itk, tomography-reconstruction

I would like to get the data of PET and CT interpolated so underlying arrays will have the same dimensions - in normal case it is simple yet I have data set where ranges of the PET and CT scans differ - hence I Would need to first trim the bigger study.

The problem is that may appear is choosing the subset of slices will lead to small yet observable part of the bigger image to overhang from the smaller ones (because voxels are of different sizes) and if I understand it correctly it may spoil the interpolation .

I suppose it is common problem so how to achieve interpolation where not only voxel dimension is different but also the range ?

Code below do not work as I would like to in case of different ranges of images

```
sitk.Resample(imagePET, ctImage)
```

Link to the mentioned dataset

https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/Public/Head-Neck-PET-CT

Comment: Well, you either use some existing library (eg. SIRF) or you just code that trimming yourself.... There is no much mystery on it, jut labour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is to read both DICOM series as a 3D image, then do the resampling, and then write the resulting image as a series of slices (in DICOM or another format). This [example](https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0/Examples/DicomSeriesReadModifyWrite/Documentation.html) should be helpful.